# How to use setState function inside the function in functional component?

Tags: javascript

I am now working on a functional component

```
const [input_error, setInputError] = useState({
   harvest:false,
   stake:false,
   unstake:false,
   deposit:false,
   withdraw:false,    
   apy:false,
   period:false,
   feeaddress:false,
   harvestfee:false,
   unstakefee1:false,
   unstakefee2:false,
   unstakefee3:false,
   unstakefee4:false,
   unstakefee5:false,
});

function set_value(e) {
   let temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(input_value));
   temp[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
   setInputValue(temp);
}
```

At this time, I cannot use set_value(e) to modify the state and render it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using react, I don't recommend doing this for immutability, use the spread operator like this:

```
setInputError({...input_error, [e.target.name]:e.target.value})
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the state is object and you should use json to set the state.
So `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(input_value));`

to string and to json again.